# How to properly use and move between react routers?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am having a hard time implementing react-routers.
The home page is this one and when I click on the red highlighted button DEPOSIT:
[image]

---

the correct component is rendered with the right url:

### [image]

but if from there I try to move to another page like stake, the url changes into /BUSD/stake instead of just /stake.

### [image]

Here is the code for the deposit button (pool.name in this case is Binance):

```
<Button
  variant="contained"
  color="primary"
  className={classes.button}
  onClick={() => {
    history.push(`${pool.name}/deposit`);
  }}
>
  {url.includes('stake') ? t('pledge') : t('deposit')}
</Button>;
```

This is the code for the links in the navbar:

```
{menuItem.map((item) => (
  <MenuItem
    classes={{
      selected: classes.selected
    }}
    className={`${classes.button} ${classes.hgbtn}`}
    component={Link}
    to={item === 'pool' ? '/' : `${item}`}
    key={item}
    selected={item === 'pool' ? location.pathname === '/' : location.pathname === `/${item}`}
  >
    {t(`${item}`)}
  </MenuItem>
))}
```

This is the code from the App.js with the routes:

```
<Router>
  <Navbar changeTheme={changeTheme} darkMode={darkMode} languages={languages} />
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/">
      <Pool className={classes.pool} pools={poolData} />
    </Route>
    <Route exact path="/stake">
      <Pool className={classes.pool} pools={stakeData} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/leverage">
      <Leverage className={classes.pool} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/lock-up">
      <LockUp className={classes.pool} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/:id/deposit">
      <PoolActions className={classes.pool} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/:id/withdraw">
      <PoolActions className={classes.pool} />
    </Route>
  </Switch>
  <Footer />
</Router>
```

Comment: You should use exact path instead of path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `to` for the menu item should probably be an absolute path (start with a slash):

```
to={item === 'pool' ? '/' : `/${item}`}
```